# How to ignore specific Mailable class in Laravel Telescope?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-telescope

I have Telescope installed on Laravel 10. The `register()` method in the `TelescopeServiceProvider.php` currently contains:

```
Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) {
    if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
        return true;
    }

    return $entry->isReportableException() ||
        $entry->isFailedRequest() ||
        $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
        $entry->hasMonitoredTag() ||
        $entry->isSlowQuery() ||
        $entry->isClientRequest() ||
        ($entry->type === EntryType::REQUEST && in_array('slow', $entry->tags)) ||
        ($entry->type === EntryType::GATE && $entry->content['result'] !== 'allowed') ||
        $entry->type === EntryType::LOG ||
        $entry->type === EntryType::JOB ||
        $entry->type === EntryType::EVENT ||
        $entry->type === EntryType::COMMAND ||
        ($entry->type === EntryType::MAIL && $entry->content['mailable'] !== 'App\Mail\Communication\CommunicationMailable');
});
```

As you can see from the last couple of lines, I'm trying to log every Mailable **except** the `CommunicationMailable` class. I'm currently doing it by a string comparison using the `mailable` property set by Telescope, but I don't really like it because if I changed the path of the mailable class I would have to remember to change the string manually each time. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mailable` property set by Telescope corresponds to the fully-qualified class name, so you can use the `::class` constant to get it programmatically ([PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)). In my case:

1. Import the `CommunicationMailable` class in `TelescopeServiceProvider.php`:

`use App\Mail\Communication\CommunicationMailable;`

2. Use the `::class` constant instead of the string written manually (from the code in the question):

```
($entry->type === EntryType::MAIL && $entry->content['mailable'] !== CommunicationMailable::class)
```